# powershell and remote signing

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I've created a power shell script to run on start-up but its not working.  I've never run a script through group policy so i don't know what the restrictions/best practices are.  I've been told i need to sign the script.  After some reading i think i need to:

1. How to create a certificate
2. How to issue the certificate to each the clients on our Windows domain
3. Sign the certificate

I've found the instructions about creating a code signing (link below ) but the address "https://server/certsrv" does not work, any ideas why? I'm looking on the windows 2008 SBS domain controller which has the certificate authority.

http://www.mikepfeiffer.net/2010/02/obtaining-a-code-signing-certificate-and-signing-powershell-scripts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Scott's PowerShell scripting signing howto here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply.  I've read through the instructions and it tells me how to create the certificate, add it to the local machine and manually add it to remote machines.  How do i automatically add the certificate to all machines in my domain? can this be done through group policy?

Comment: @resolver101 Yep you sure can. Here's a howto: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770315(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Both Instructions worked a treat.  I also use PowerGUI so downloaded the script signing plugin.  I also created a group policy for all sign and attached this to the computers container.  "Computer configuration -> administrative templates -> windows components -> Windows powershell -> turn on script execution -> all signed "

Comment: @resolver101 Glad this helped. I use PowerGUI too, its the best :-)